# Vuetify Carousel syncing with route params

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to sync `v-carousel` value with a route parameter using a computed property. For some reason, the carousel emits an input and ignoring the initial value from route param, even if I make it wait for the `mounted` hook.

So even if the original route param is `1` (`/test-route/1`), it changes to `0` (`/test-route/0`) after loading.

How can I initialize and sync the carousel value with a route parameter?

```js
<template>
  <v-carousel v-model="ind" >
    <v-carousel-item
      v-for="(item, i) in images"
      :key="i"
    >
      <v-img :src="item.image_thumb200" />
    </v-carousel-item>
  </v-carousel>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['images'],
  data: ()=>({
    // ind: 1,
    isMounted: false,
  }),
  watch: {
    "$route.params": {
      handler: function(val){
        console.log("route",val)
      },
      deep: true,
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ind:{
      get(){
        console.log('get: ',this.$route.params.id)
        return this.$route.params.id
      },
      set(val){
        if(this.isMounted){
          console.log('set: ',val)
          this.$router.push({params: {id: val}})
        }
      }
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    console.log('mounted')
    this.isMounted = true
  }
}
</script>
```

console output:

```
get:  1
mounted
set:  0
route {id: 0}
get:  0
```

Comment: can you add `console.log` before route push? So we can see how many times param passes

Comment: Asimple, Added console outputs to getters, setters and route params.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to convert the route param to `Number`. So instead of the getter

```js
get(){
  return this.$route.params.id
},
```

I should have used

```js
get(){
  return Number(this.$route.params.id)
},
```